# Store mongoose field values into a var and interate through

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Been making great waves getting deeper into node.js and mongo but I've hit a bit of a wall.
I've got my data being pushing from a form into a collection with mongoose and I can see it being pulled into a JS file and calling the document with console.log below.

```
var fields = { 'cheap': 1, 'number': 1 };
var query = userModel.find({}).select(fields);

query.exec(function (err, docs) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log(docs + 'first');

  request(url, function(error, response, html) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          var $ = cheerio.load(html);
          //var $el = $("a:contains('Xbox')");
          var $el = $('a:contains(' + docs + ')');
          console.log(docs + 'second')

          if ($el.length) {
          client.messages.create({
            to: "+ '+ cheap.number +'",
            from: "+61418739508",
            body: $el.text()
          }, function(err, message) {
            if(err){
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              console.log(message.sid);
            }
          });
            console.log($el.text());
        } else {
            console.log('hey');
        }
      }
  });
});
```

Output:

```
[ { _id: 561650245b3d0d57ad7f3c72,
    cheap: 'menus',
    number: '0000000000' } ]
```

However, now I would like to take the values of the 'cheap' and 'number' fields and store them as a var that I can iterate through on the below function.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for what I need to work on? It very much seems like an elusive missing piece of a puzzle.

Comment: Are you sure output of this log `console.log(cheap);` is `[ { _id: 561650245b3d0d57ad7f3c72,
    cheap: 'menus',
    number: '0000000000' } ]`
And what about the number param (callback of  `exec`  func)?

Comment: 100% sure, number param is disappearing, I've removed it and just left `cheap` and the console log result remains the same. However, stripping out the `number` field from `var fields` will only return the obj id and `cheap`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the mongoose is async, you should move the request function to `exec` something like this

```
` query.exec(function (err, cheap, number) {
   if (err) return handleError(err);
   console.log(cheap);
   request(url, function(error, response, html) {
     if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
     var $ = cheerio.load(html);

     async.each(cheap, function(iterateCheap, callback){
        var $el = $("a:contains(" + cheap + ")");

     }, function(err){
        if(err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log('We successfully iterate on all cheap')
        }
     })
     ......`
```

**UPDATE1:**
Or you should use async.js module and `waterfall` method for this situation

Comment: Sorry sorry have updated this to be more clear. That works fine and I still receive the same console.log output. However my specific issue is how do i call the value from the `cheap` and `number` fields of the output?

Comment: it's obvious , cheap return array data type you should iterate and return appropriate value.

Comment: Can you please provide a brief code example or point me to some documentation? I'm missing something.

Comment: Hi @alireza david please see answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Found what I was looking for. Needed a `for.. in`  construct to iterate through the properties of the object. From there I had to call the object and property type and it works.

Magic that fixed it:

```
  var docs;
  for (var key in docs) {
     var value = docs[key];
     console.log(key + ", " + value);
  }
```

Full code:

```
var query = userModel.find({});

query.exec(function (err, docs) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  //console.log(docs);

  var docs;
  for (var key in docs) {
     var value = docs[key];
     console.log(key + ", " + value);
  }

  request(url, function(error, response, html) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          var $ = cheerio.load(html);
          //var $el = $("a:contains('Xbox')");
          var $el = $('a:contains(' + value.cheap + ')');
          //console.log($el);

          if ($el.length) {
          client.messages.create({
            to: value.number,
            from: "+61418739508",
            body: $el.text()
          }, function(err, message) {
            if(err){
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              console.log(message.sid);
            }
          });
            console.log($el.text());
        } else {
            console.log('hey');
        }
      }
  });
});
```